# how can I create relationship others table with registration table?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I created tables in sql and tried to connect them with registration all remaining tabeles by using foreign and primery key, but does not work as I want. Can you help me how to connect each other?

The tables are:

1, registration

```
Create Table Registration
(
ID int NOT NULL primary key,
FirstName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(25) NOT NULL,  

    Username varchar(20), 
    Gender varchar(10),
    Home_Address varchar(100),
    Office_Address varchar(100), 
    City varchar(25), 
    State varchar(25), 
    Zip varchar(25), 
    Contact_No int , 
    Email varchar(25)
);
```

2 posts

```
CREATE TABLE Post

( p_id int constraint p_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), 
Status varchar(25), 
image nvarchar(max),
date_time varchar(100)
);
```

3,

```
CREATE TABLE Books
(
ISBN nvarchar(200) constraint ISBN_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), 
Book_title varchar(25), 
Authorname varchar(25), 
Publicationdate varchar(25),
Purchasedate varchar(25),
Book_edition varchar(25)
);
```

4,

```
CREATE TABLE images
(I_id int constraint i_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), 
Title varchar(25), 
url varchar(50), 
description varchar(100)
);
```

5,

```
CREATE TABLE laptop
(
L_id int constraint L_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), 
Model varchar(25), 
Speed varchar(25), 
Ram varchar(25), 
HD varchar(50), 
Screen varchar(50)
);
```

6, other items

```
CREATE TABLE other_items
(O_id int constraint O_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), 
Item_title varchar(25), 
Item_type varchar(25), 
Item_description varchar(100), 
Itempicture varchar(100)
);
```

7, recipient

```
CREATE TABLE Recipient
(R_id int constraint R_pk   primary key, 
Firstname varchar(25), 
Lastname varchar(25), 
National_id_no varchar(50),
Address varchar(100),
Contact_no varchar(100)
);
```

8

```
CREATE TABLE Shoesimages
(
s_id int constraint Rss_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), standard varchar(25), 
Gender varchar(25), 
Colour varchar(25), 
Description varchar(100)
);
```

9,

```
CREATE TABLE uniform
(U_id int constraint u_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), 
Standard varchar(25), 
Gender varchar(25), 
Colour varchar(25), 
Description varchar(100)
);
```

10,

```
CREATE TABLE Research_paper
(
Rs_id int constraint Rs_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar(25), 
title varchar(25), 
authorname varchar(25), 
year_of_publish varchar(25),
venu varchar(100)
);
```

11,

```
CREATE TABLE Comments
(
C_id int constraint C_pk   primary key, 
Username varchar2(25), 
comment nvarchar(max), 
date_time varchar2(100)
);
```

Comment: You need to add [foreign key constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I know and I have been trying to create foreign key but it does not work as i want it. I need a suggestion how can i connect it with foreign that can connect all tables with registartion tables

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is not working as you want? Looking at your tables, you have `username` everywhere for example, why not relate everything to the `ID` field in the registration table.

Comment: i tried to connect username with ID of the Registration table, it gives me error, it says username and ID is different data types cant be create relationship

Comment: Well that is expected because in the current design `username` is a `varchar2(25)` and `ID` is an `int`. If you want to enforce a FK, the types must match.

Comment: so, is there any way that helps me to connect to each other ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described in the comments, you just need to edit your create table statements to make the types agree.

If you are trying to link Username from table Post to ID from table Registration the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the Post table will have to look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE Post
(
    p_id int constraint p_pk   primary key, 
    user_id int NOT NULL, --This refers to Registration.ID and matches the type defined there
    Status varchar(25), 
    image nvarchar(max),
    date_time varchar(100),     
    FOREIGN KEY ( user_id) REFERENCES [Registration] ( id ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Do you mean that I have to change username data types including the one exsit in Registration table? if I use int data types for a username, so user can use characters for username?

Comment: What I am suggesting is rather than relate the different tables through `Username` use the `ID` field that is from the Registration table. In the Post table, I created a field called `user_id` to hold the FK from Registration.

Comment: ok, I got you. I will try to relate them by user_ID. thank you so much